# Creating a reusable class

Tags: java, android, class

I have an application running in Android, i wanna create a Menu and repeat in some activities, that menu calls Intent for open others activities.

How can i do this?

Think maybe i can create a class, but i getting errors. Where can i create a class for that? Inside onCreate method or not?
And how can i reuse the menu in another activity?

Thanks!!

Here is my menu code:

```
menu_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
    menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, menu_button);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.one:
                            Intent vista = new Intent(MainActivity.this, openCamera.class);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(vista);

                    }
                    return true;

                    /*
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                    */
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can make _BaseActivity_ in which your menu will be. Extends your activity with base activity in which you want menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the menu is always the same and you want to reuse it in more than one activity, you just define it like this:

```
public class TestMenu {

    private final PopupMenu popupMenu;

    public TestMenu(final Activity activity, View anchor) {
        popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity, anchor);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.one:
                        Intent vista = new Intent(activity, openCamera.class);
                        activity.startActivity(vista);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void show() {
        popupMenu.show();
    }
}
```

And then use it in your activity like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button menu_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
        TestMenu myMenu = new TestMenu(this, menu_button);
        menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```